# what classes should I take so that I can perform research into finding catalysts to split water into oxygen and hydrogen?

Tags: chemical-engineering, photovoltaics

I am a freshman student and I am very interested in using solar energy to break water into hydrogen and oxygen. So, I want to know which areas are important in this regard..

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but back in days when i was ... i used to expose my photovoltaic cell towards the sun light and put the two electrodes inside a water tank, then it did what you ask for. I think that's the easy way ...

Comment: What do you mean by "areas of importance"? Do you mean areas of study that you should pursue as a freshman? Do you mean areas where what you want to do is used in real life? Do you mean areas where you should take care not to blow yourself up when you do this in your kitchen at home?

Comment: Based upon your title, I can presume you are asking "what classes should I take so that I can perform research into finding catalysts to split water into oxygen and hydrogen?"  If so, please reword your question as such.  If not, please reword.  As such, the comments left by @JeffreyJWeimer stand and I will vote to close for being unclear.  Thanks!

Comment: Even if the classes are not offered, I can look up books on that subject and start right away!

Comment: Books only go so far. At the undergrad level, you _must_ have the training, discipline, and experience that is gained by taking the courses. I might add that, hands-on research requires laboratory experience that is built through training in undergrad labs (see below).

Comment: Career and education advice is off-topic for the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At your level, start with the two semesters of general chemistry. You will need a solid basis in chemical dynamics, redox chemistry, and chemical thermodynamics. Next take physical chemistry, especially when it includes electrochemistry. This will expand your understanding of the three core topics. Finally, take a course that covers aspects of heterogeneous catalysis, for example as offered in chemical engineering departments. This will explain  how to translate the core topics from bulk systems to surfaces. As you move to graduate school, you should take courses in catalysis, solid state chemistry/physics, and electrochemistry.

Undergrad curricula in chemistry, chemical engineering, or materials science (not materials engineering) should provide what you need. Graduate curricula would be in the same fields.

Do **not** neglect to take the associated laboratory courses as an undergraduate. You *must* learn how to do experiments in general chemistry and physical chemistry. You *must* learn how to keep certifiable notebooks, review literature, write well-structured technical reports, and prepare publishable-level documents on your research. These skills are built from the groundings in the undergraduate laboratories, they do not just magically appear because you show up one day fully enthused and excited to do your research work in a laboratory.

Comment: If I were to start research on the subject from undergrad, it is possible, right? I want my final year project( in my fourth year) to be based on photovoltaic splitting of water.

Comment: Undergrad research is possible and indeed a good idea in the hard sciences/engineering going toward grad school. First determine whether your department has courses in undergrad research. Alternatively or in addition, explore official summer programs for undergrad research, often called research and creative experiences for undergraduates (RCEU). You want the research experience on your transcript, and you could get paid for doing it. Next, find a faculty member who will support you. You cannot do undergrad research without a faculty mentor, primarily to keep you from going astray.

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to be expert in (at least) these fields:

- photocatalysis
- electrochemistry
- photovoltaics

In addition, you'll have to become intimately familiar with the published efforts others have made in this field over the last 45 years or so.